# Can't ajust uicollectionview height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, keyboard

I have a ViewController with some header view in it and a UICollectionView who fill all the remaining space. (it's a chat app)

I'm not using storyboard. My collection view is declared this way :

```
self.messagesCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - barHeight), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
messagesCollectionView.register(MessageCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier)
messagesCollectionView.delegate = self
messagesCollectionView.dataSource = self
self.view.addSubview(messagesCollectionView)
```

Then I have theses func to get my data correctly :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.conversation?.messagesList.count ?? 0
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell

    if let message = self.conversation?.messagesList[indexPath.row] {
        cell.createMessage(message: message)
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let message = self.conversation?.messagesList[indexPath.row] {
        var heightNeeded = message.text.height(withConstrainedWidth: FDDimensions.shared.k_MessageMaxWidth, font: FDFonts.Montserrat_Regular_14 ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14))
        heightNeeded += 22
        heightNeeded += 25

        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: heightNeeded)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
}
```

So here is an example of what I get, with good aspect before resizing it :

[image]

The thing I want to do is resize my collectionview height when the keyboard appears.

Here is the code in my func who is triggered when the keyboard show up :

```
self.messagesCollectionView.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height - (FDUtils.shared.getBottomSafeAreaHeight() ?? 0)
self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
self.messagesCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Here is the result I get : 
[image]

All my cells are changed and the result is completely broken

Any idea where I'm wrong ? I've tried to just ajust the contentInsets of the collectionView but I can't use that because the scrollbar behavior won't be logic if I use that solution

Thanks

Comment: too little of a code to know what is going on, are you doing it on main thread?

Comment: Yes I am. What code would you need ?

Comment: your `keyboard show up` code

Comment: Just a regular listener on keyboardWillShow and then I just get the keyboard height. I mean it could be any height different the problem would be the same it's not related to the specific keyboard height

Comment: regular listener would work :) that is why I ask for code because this is not related to height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer, thanks to them who helped

The problem was in my cellForRowAt func.

My func cell.createMessage wasn't resizing my white cell for message good, I'm not sure why because my sizeForItemAt func seems to works great but I managed to fix the problem just by re-calculing my cell height directly in the createMessage func

Answer (score 0):

Add the listener when the keyboard is raised

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

@objc func showKeyboard(notification: Notification) {

        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: messagesList.count - 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of changing height of collectionView, Change the contentInset of collectionView

Below Code will help you.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func addKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillhide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillAppear(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillAppear(notification: Notification) {
    if var keyBoardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject?)?.cgRectValue?.size.height {
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.height >= 812.0 {
            keyBoardHeight -= 34.0
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            //self.collectionViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyBoardHeight
            collectionView.contentInset.bottom = keyBoardHeight
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillhide(notification: Notification) {
     collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use constraint, what should I do to set this up ?

Comment: check my updated code. Change the contentInset instead of height.

Answer (score 0):

try following line while keyboard is up, because reload not changing your cell frames for that you need to call invalidateLayout() func.

```
self.messagesCollectionView.frame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height - (FDUtils.shared.getBottomSafeAreaHeight() ?? 0)
    self.messagesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: i'm not clearly see your UI corrupted screen can you upload that so will think accordingly

Comment: ok, if is this demo app can you post that code so will debug and find solution. im sure about previous layout is not invalidate here.

Comment: can you please share the expected result image.

Comment: @SGDev check above comment this posted.